# Datadog .rollup(sum, 60) vs .rollup(avg, 60) aggregation meaning

Tags: aggregate, aggregation, monitor, datadog

What does .rollup(sum, 60) and .rollup(avg, 60) mean?
This is my understanding

> .rollup(sum, 60) - sum up values every second for 60 seconds.
> .rollup(avg, 60) - sum up values every second for 60 seconds and then
> divide by 60.

Taking the example in screenshot, a time range of 5 mins produces these data points

> .rollup(sum, 60) : 863, 1570, 1470, 819, 988

> .rollup(avg, 60) : 215.75, 391.25, 368.5, 204.75, 247
> (note: all the avg values produced are a factor of 4, ex: 863/215.75 =
> 4)

However, as per my understanding, it should have produced these values (863/60s = 14.38)

> .rollup(avg, 60) - 14.38, 26.16, 24.5, 13.65, 16.46

What am I missing?

The metric is a counter metric published to datadog

```
applicationMonitor.counter(metric).increment();
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the metric type? Have you tried using the `as_count` in-app modifier? https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/type_modifiers/?tab=count#in-application-modifiers

Answer (score 1):

The `.rollup()` function applies "[time aggregation](https://docs.datadoghq.com/dashboards/guide/query-to-the-graph/#proceed-to-time-aggregation)" -- it groups up your values in time buckets and shows you the selected aggregation of those values.

So with a `.rollup(sum, 60)` for each 60 second period you will see the "sum" of all the data points it contains. With `.rollup(avg, 60)`, for each 60 second period you will see the "avg" of all the data points that it contains.

Sounds like whatever it is that's incrementing the counts has a "flush interval" of 15 seconds, since you seem to consistently have 4 values reported every minute. If your goal is to see "the average count value per 15 seconds over time" then the `.rollup(avg, N)` may be for you. If your goal is to see the "total count per minute" then `.rollup(sum, 60)` should get you there (but note, if you expand to a time-range of larger than 300 minutes, you'll see the rollup's time-bucket size grow to larger than 1 minute).